# How to update values in HashMap with LinkedList?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list, hashmap

This is my HashMap:

```
public static HashMap<String, LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>> partitionMap;
partitionMap = new HashMap<String, LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>>();
```

My program has a initial step of initialization where all keys are added, without values. After that, I need to retrieve the key and add the value.
The problem is that I got the null pointer exception even if I initizalize the LinkedList.

INIT step:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> ll = new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>();
partitionMap.put(key, ll);
```

After that:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> l = partitionMap.get(key);
l.add(partition);  //CRASH, null pointer exception
partitionMap.put(key, l);
```

The problem is related to the LinkedList and its initialization. Is there a way to avoid this problem?

EDIT: full code.

```
   //This function is called N time to fill the partitionMap with only keys
   public void init(DLRParser.SignatureContext ctx) {
    LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> l = new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>();
    partitionMap.put(ctx.getText(), l);
}

  //After that, this function is called to fill partitionMap with only values
public void processing(DLRParser.MultiProjectionContext ctx) {  
    LinkedList<String> partition = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (TerminalNode terminalNode : ctx.U()) {
        partition.add(terminalNode.getText());
    }
    Collections.reverse(partition);

    //iteration on another HashMap with the same keys, if we have a match
    //then add the values to the partitionMap
    for(Entry<String, LinkedList<String>> entry : tableMap.entrySet())
    {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        LinkedList<String> attributes = entry.getValue();
        if(attributes.containsAll(partition)) //match
        {
            //retrieve the LinkedList of LinkedList with value
            LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> l = partitionMap.get(key);
            l.add(partition); // CRASH - Nullpointer exception
            partitionMap.put(key, l); //add it -
            System.out.println(l.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the full code , as variables mentioned are missing declaration

Comment: is partitionMap.get(key); always returning the value? Just debug the program or add a System.out.println and get the values there for partitionMap.get(key)

Comment: Ok I got the error. It returns always null, but that's because I need to get the key itself, not the value that in init step are all null.

Comment: great job, debugging code most of the times solves the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `putIfAbsent` method added in java8 for initializing List with default values

```
    HashMap<String, List<List<String>>> partitionMap = new HashMap<String, List<List<String>>>();
    partitionMap.putIfAbsent("a", new LinkedList<>(new LinkedList<>()));
    partitionMap.get("a").add(Arrays.asList("b"));
```